# Why can't able to show UP button icon in toolbar at android fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing a news app in android.I have following stuff

- Android drawer
- Main activity
- News Item Fragment
- News Itemdetails Fragment
- Toolbar

News Item Fragment is first page in the app. It has one listview which shows news item. When user clicks on a item in the listview it opens second page (News Itemdetails Fragment). I want to show UP button icon on the toolbar when second page is active so that user can return to the first page again. To show the UP button in the toolbar I have tried 'setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled' in the 'News Itemdetails Fragment'(Second Page), but it throws errors when a item is clicked in 'News Item Fragment' (First Page).

I have given following details for your reference.

**News Item Fragment**

```
package com.uss.navigationdrawer3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        String[] planets = new String[] { "News Item 1", "News Item 2", "News Item 3","News Item 4","News Item 5","News Item 6"
        };
        final ListView listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_fragment_home);

        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, planets);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,R.id.product_name,planets);
        //ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        //        R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, planets);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int itemPosition     = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();


                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new MessageFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Message Fragment");
            }
        });
        inputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           // When user changed the Text
           HomeFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                     int arg3) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }


   }
        );


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

}
```

**News Itemdetails Fragment**

```
package com.uss.navigationdrawer3;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment{

    Toolbar toolbar;

    public MessageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);

        toolbar=(Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (activity != null) {
            ActionBar ab = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            if (ab != null) {
                ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        toolbar.setTitle("Title");

        return view;
    }

}
```

**Errors**

```
12-14 12:06:37.675    2005-2005/com.uss.navigationdrawer3 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
12-14 12:06:37.675    2005-2005/com.uss.navigationdrawer3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.uss.navigationdrawer3, PID: 2005
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:94)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:87)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:77)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:96)
        at com.uss.navigationdrawer3.MessageFragment.onCreateView(MessageFragment.java:36)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-14 12:06:37.867    2005-2017/com.uss.navigationdrawer3 I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3409(281KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 1831KB/2MB, paused 77.322ms total 183.824ms
12-14 12:11:37.853    2005-2005/com.uss.navigationdrawer3 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2005 SIG: 9
```

Please help how to go to first page from second page when Up button is pressed in toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have defined your toolbar in activity xml and trying to access it in fragment that returns toolbar value